# ftpputfile for goanywhere server

Tags: visual-c++, ftp

I am using below code to transfer file to FTP server.

```
bPS = ::FtpPutFile(m_hPSFTPConnection,tempfile,uniqueFname,INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_ASCII,(DWORD) this);
```

With this, I was able to transfer the file while using old connection configuration.

Now, server configuration has been changed. And now we are using Go Anywhere server.

So, I just changed the configuration parameters like IP, username, password, and port (21) as per the new server configuration. but ftpputfile is not working. It is returning value 0. Using winscp we can manually transfer the file. but through the application using API ftpputfile it is not working. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Could anyone reply on this ? any help ?

Comment: What does [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) report?